# Python requests module slow due to high number of internal function calls

Tags: python, python-requests, .netrc

On one of my machines the Python module `requests` is extremely slow, seemingly due to a very high number of internal function calls. What could lead to such an issue?

```py
>>> import sys, cProfile, requests, urllib3
>>> sys.version
'3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0]'
>>> requests.__version__
'2.28.1' # same issue with latest 2.29.0 release

>>> cProfile.run('requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080")', sort='ncalls')
        11717750 function calls (11717748 primitive calls) in 10.091 seconds

    Ordered by: call count

    ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   5220221    0.770   0.000     0.775    0.000 {method 'read' of '_io.TextIOWrapper' objects}
   5220221    0.801   0.000     0.801    0.000 shlex.py:68(punctuation_chars)
    468483    0.364   0.000     9.564    0.000 shlex.py:101(get_token)
    401557    7.612   0.000     9.188    0.000 shlex.py:133(read_token)
    200797    0.059   0.000     0.059    0.000 {method 'startswith' of 'str' objects}
     66931    0.012   0.000     0.012    0.000 {method 'popleft' of 'collections.deque' objects}
     66926    0.012   0.000     0.012    0.000 {method 'appendleft' of 'collections.deque' objects}
     66926    0.049   0.000     0.061    0.000 shlex.py:72(push_token)
      [..] # remaining calls with significantly lower numbers

>>> cProfile.run('http=urllib3.PoolManager(); http.request("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8080")', sort='ncalls')
        784 function calls (783 primitive calls) in 0.005 seconds
```

On another machines, running the same version of Python and tested with
same versions of `requests`, things look about right:

```py
>>> cProfile.run('requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080")', sort='ncalls')
        2432 function calls (2396 primitive calls) in 0.005 seconds
```

- Above tests were done using `python3 -m http.server 8080 --bind 127.0.0.1`,
  but same results for other HTTP servers
- Most of the time spent is before a TCP connection is even created by looking
  at network traffic using `tcpdump`
- As with `urllib3`, completely unrelated tools such as `curl` works just fine
- While tests were made on IPv4 addresses, actively disabling IPv6 for
  `requests` using `requests.packages.urllib3.util.connection.HAS_IPV6 = False`
  did not have any effect either
- Tested with clean virtualenvs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Python profile viewer [tuna](https://github.com/nschloe/tuna) I found
that `requests` will attempt to get authentication
credentials from a netrc file (`$HOME/.netrc` or `$HOME/_netrc`) if no other
authentication method is specified:

- https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/#netrc-authentication
- https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/v2.28.1/requests/sessions.py#L478

Instead of just looking at number of calls (`ncalls`), sorting by cumulative
time (`sort=cumtime`) would also have helped highlight how the issuing of
`netrc.py` and subsequent `shlex.py` were the main culprits.

In my case I had a fairly large netrc file at thousands of entries. Upon
trimming or removing the netrc file entirely the subsequent number of function
calls shrunk accordingly.

---

Ideally the performance of the `netrc` Python module wouldn't be such a
bottleneck, as the file itself isn't all that complex, and other programs like
`curl` has no issues handling it, but oh well.